# OSB Database poller 12c sometimes not polling records from db

Tags: database, proxy, soa, osb, poller

I have experienced that the osb 12c db poller was working fine , but all of sudden it stopped polling records from the db. When checked the logs found that 2 out of 4 managed nodes memory was filled. But the other 2 were working fine.

Not sure why it stopped polling records all of sudden. Can someone please assist  here. Below is the JCA properties.

```
<property name="DescriptorName" value="SpinWinDBUpdate.SpinnwinPoll"/>
  <property name="QueryName" value="SpinWinDBUpdateSelect"/>
  <property name="MappingsMetaDataURL" value="SpinWinDBUpdate-or-mappings.xml"/>
  <property name="PollingStrategy" value="LogicalDeletePollingStrategy"/>
  <property name="MarkReadColumn" value="STATUS_CODE"/>
  <property name="MarkReadValue" value="1"/>
  <property name="MarkUnreadValue" value="0"/>
  <property name="PollingInterval" value="5"/>
  <property name="MaxRaiseSize" value="1"/>
  <property name="MaxTransactionSize" value="10"/>
  <property name="NumberOfThreads" value="1"/>
  <property name="ReturnSingleResultSet" value="false"/>
  <property name="RowsPerPollingInterval" value="2"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Distributed Polling in case of using the DB adapter in a clustered environment. For more information https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15586_01/integration.1111/e10231/adptr_db.htm#BDCIJGAJ

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the issue still persist intermittently.